# Java ArrayBlockingQueue take source

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking

When I was reading source code of ArrayBlockingQueue.take method, I got a problem.

I think then two threads call take method concurrently, only one thread could successfully get lock, and the other thread would waiting on the lock at the line:`lock.lockInterruptibly();`
this is source code of take:

```
public E take() throws InterruptedException {
    final ReentrantLock lock = this.lock;
    lock.lockInterruptibly();
    try {
        while (count == 0)
            notEmpty.await();
        return dequeue();
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

But when I make a thread dump of the two threads, I found that both threads got lock successfully, and waiting on line:`notEmpty.await();`(because queue is empty)
This is the thread dump:

> "test-thread-18" #6357 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f8f54543000 nid=0x58ef waiting on condition [0x00007f901bc70000]
>      java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
>     at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
>     - parking to wait for  <0x00007f93ae695410> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
>     at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
>     at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.take(ArrayBlockingQueue.java:403)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> "test-thread-17" #6356 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f8f54542000 nid=0x58ee waiting on condition [0x00007f901beb9000]
>      java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
>     at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
>     - parking to wait for  <0x00007f93ae695410> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
>     at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
>     at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.take(ArrayBlockingQueue.java:403)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

So, why two different thread could get the same lock on same time?
What's wrong with my understand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only one thread can hold the `ReentrantLock` on the same time.

`notEmpty` is an [`Condition`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) object, current thread will release the lock when calling [`Condition.await()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html#await()):

> Causes the current thread to wait until it is signalled or
> interrupted. The lock associated with this Condition is **atomically
> released** and the current thread becomes disabled for thread scheduling
> purposes and lies dormant until one of four things happens:
>
> - Some other thread invokes the signal() method for this Condition and
>   the current thread happens to be chosen as the thread to be awakened;
> - or Some other thread invokes the signalAll() method for this
>   Condition;
> - or Some other thread interrupts the current thread, and
>   interruption of thread suspension is supported;
>   -or A "spurious wakeup"
>   occurs.
>
> In all cases, before this method can return the current thread
> must **re-acquire** the lock associated with this condition. When the
> thread returns it is guaranteed to hold this lock.

Comment: You should explicitly point out that `notEmpty` is a [`Condition`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) bound to `lock`, since that is not apparent from the code in the question.

Comment: Thanks.You point out that condition.await() will release lock,which a didn't know before. With this knowledge,I can understand the where the problem is.